# Running automated tests for Unity apps on iOS/Android devices?

Tags: automated-testing, unit-tests, mobile, android, ios

I want to run automated tests for a game that I am developing with [Unity](http://www.unity3d.com). It runs on iOS and Android devices. As a first step we would like to

- Launch the game on device type X
- If the game loaded on the device within some timeout without crashing:

  - Pass the test
- Otherwise

  - Fail the test

I want to run those tests on all device types and generate reports based on the test results. E.g. the devices could open a URL and send the results in the request body.

**Is there a way to automate such a test for a Unity application running on actual devices?**

I would prefer using an existing tool for that. If this does not exist yet, I assume I have to create some wrapper around my app and catch crash signals in order to report test failures.

Comment: AFAIK, You can write the test cases in Xcode and then run them so that they will give you the results in Pass/Fail format.

Comment: I am sure you can, but what I referring to was how to this in a [mobile application written in Unity](http://www.unity3d.com).

Answer (score 1):

- For iOS I would like to suggest **Test Studio** which is an existing tool. You can download this app from AppStore and integrate its extension in your app. Once its done then you can run your app from the **Test Studio** and can record your script for the app. This script can be shared with different iOS devices using their web portal and you can run the script on different iOS devices.
- For Android I have not used any tool that will actually work on real devices but there is one site **TestObject** that provides web based simulators for almost all popular devices. On this site you can record the script for one simulator and can execute same script on another simulators also.
- From last few day I have started using MonkeyTalk IDE for Android apps (you can try this tool for iOS also but I haven't used it for iOS and it gives some problem in integrating agent for iOS. We're figuring out the solution.) MonkeyTalk is open source tool and can be used efficiently. Yes, it has some drawbacks/shortcomings but still its a good tool.

Answer (score 1):

SeeTest by Experitest is a decent tool that might match your needs.
[SeeTest](http://experitest.com/)

It works on the GUI level, but can interface API's beneath it too.